# uwsgi nginx selinux on centos 7 audit2allow done, enforcing selinux still blocking access to the socket

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, centos7, selinux

I'm trying to add a flask uwsgi behind nginx with SELinux activated but no luck so far.

I've followed all suggestions to pipe denied contexts from `audit.log` to `audit2allow` generating the module and then `semodule -i nginx.pp` as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26336047/2172543 but still, if I leave `setenforce 1` nginx is being blocked to write to the socket.

I've also changed permissions to all folders in /path/to/socket.sock, changed umask of the socket to 666, did everything where there was a solution for my problem but I'm still getting 502 with `setenforce 1`.

Switching `setenforce 0` "solves" the problem. But I want to leave SELinux activated and I have no more clues into how to further investigate the issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

format log file

`yum install setroubleshoot -y`

`sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log > /var/log/audit/audit.format.log`

allow this access for now by executing

`ausearch -c 'nginx' --raw | audit2allow -M my-nginx`

`semodule -i my-nginx.pp`