# nginx uWSGI connection to unix socket failed

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, nginx, centos7

I'm trying to connect uWSGI Flask application on CentOS 7 with nginx, nginx error log at /var/log/nginx/error.log gives:

```
2017/10/04 22:35:29 [crit] 24381#0: *54 connect() to unix:/var/www/html/CON29Application1/socket.sock failed 
(13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 80.44.138.51, 
server: 188.226.174.121, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/www/html/CON29Application1/socket.sock:",
host: "188.226.174.121", referrer: "http://188.226.174.121/"
```

uWSGI error log shows I think that uWSGI running correctly:

```
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x1a1ebd0 pid: 26364 (default app)
```

This is my first deployment on Linux, but read another SO answer here: [Nginx can't access a uWSGI unix socket on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334526/nginx-cant-access-a-uwsgi-unix-socket-on-centos-7)
This guy answered his own question, and referred to blog post on SE Linux http://axilleas.me/en/blog/2013/selinux-policy-for-nginx-and-gitlab-unix-socket-in-fedora-19/, saying SE Linux was the problem. I don't really understand what is running where on SE Linux, and solution seems to involve altering "AVC" messages in nginx audit.log, I'm getting in over my head!

As the blog post referred, I do get AVC messages mentioning denied write and nginx at /var/log/audit/audit.log:

```
 type=AVC msg=audit(1507153878.777:559609): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=24381 
comm="nginx" name="socket.sock" dev="vda1" ino=715975 
scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=sock_file
```

But being a newbie, is there perhaps something simpler perhaps I did wrong and can fix with chmod permissions or chown? Thanks any ideas.
Socket permissions:

```
ls -l socket.sock
srwxrwxrwx. 1 will nginx 0 Oct  4 17:02 socket.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, my SELinux settings did make a difference in the end, and changing this has got my web application actually working! I looked at another tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-selinux-on-centos-7-part-1-basic-concepts

I must say from a Linux newbie's point of view, I have seen a few other posts mentioning how good Digital Ocean's tutorials are (I certainly don't have any affiliation with them whatsoever..).

For other newbies reading this, SELinux stands for Security Enhanced Linux, and is something included with many distributions of Linux now apparently, including CentOS 7. It's there for added security of some kind. I ran the simplest command they list on this page: `getenforce`
which output

`enforcing`

As the Digital Ocean tutorial states, "SELinux should currently be disabled", mine wasn't - no idea why, I hadn't touched anything on SELinux as had no idea what it was until 2 days ago.

Anyway, trying for simplest fix, as their advice did:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

Or actually I think I didnt have permission to do this as my user, had to do it as root:

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

There's only actually 2 settings in this file. So reset:

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

Then tried `reboot` as their advice to restart server, so apparently then SE Linux will start logging some security mumbo jumbo stuff, ie I think this means it records security booboos and people hacking into the system rather than stopping them. Reboot then asked me for Cloud something password, which I thought must be my sudo password, it wasn't, then crashed after trying this couple times anyway, so restarted it I think this is reboot yes? And my website now works.

As the other post I mentioned here, I think this means SELinux doing something to stop nginx running when it is set to `enforcing`. But the other post here seemed bit more complex for a newbie than to just change one setting as I have done here, more potential to create further problems. If I can ever develop this or another app further, i think need to find someone with more Linux experience.